# Get ResourceId for a programatically created control in Android

Tags: android

I have created controls in android pragmatically by reading an xml

For Example

```
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
checkbox.setText("Text");
```

I would like to get the values in the control at a later stage dynamically

```
View view = this.findViewById(resId);
bool checked = ((CheckBox)view).isChecked();
```

How do I "resId" for the control created pragmatically.
I tried to use `checkbox.getId()` but it is returning 0

Comment: first set the ID to the `Checkbox` using `checkbox.setId(int)`...

Comment: are you sure that your xml specified an id?

Comment: I had tried to use setId, it is not helping either..

Comment: @Mallik : are you adding checkbox in current Activity Layout?

Comment: If you are adding your view dynamically, what is the need to setting its ID  ?

Comment: If still you want the set the ID make sure it is unique with other resource ID's.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K, I use the Activity context and add the controls

Comment: @Deepchand, Once I have created the view dynamically, I need also read the values entered by the user in them.

Comment: Make the reference global in your class, you can access it for any thing after initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better keep reference to your control and use it to set values.

```
   Map<String, CheckBox > checkBoxes = new HashMap<String, CheckBox >();
   ...
   checkBoxes.put("checkBox1", new CheckBox(this));
   ...
   CheckBox checkbox = checkBoxes.get("checkBox1");
```

But if you really want id you can set your custom id via `setId` method as @Merlevede suggested but let android generate the id to avoid conflicts. Create a xml resource item:

```
   <item type="id" name="your_super_puper_id"/>
```

And then use it: `xxx.setId(R.id.your_super_puper_id)`

To find `View`s you can use tagging. Using `setTag` method you can attach any object to a view and then use that object to find view via `findViewWithTag` method.

```
   String superPuperStringId = "checkBox1";
   someView.setTag(superPuperStringId);
   ...
   view = someViewGroup.findViewWithTag(superPuperStringId);
```

Also you can create your checkbox via xml and assign id there.

Comment: But I don't know how many Id's I would require..it needs to be dynamic

Comment: You can set tag to checkbox. And use findViewByTag. Use any tags you want. Udating answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom ID using `checkbox.setID(25)` (for example), you need to provide a unique ID. The problem that you may encounter is that there's and ID collision with some other control (if you're also using a layout XML), because the IDs are generated automatically.
I would suggest keeping your `checkbox` variable as a member of your class, so that yo can access it later on.

Comment: I do setID at the time of creating the control, but getID is returning 0. I have multiple controls in the xml, so I create them in a loop and then read them in a loop.